# Instagram auto reply direct message

Tags: instagram-api

I'm asking for your help. I'm looking to build a robot that can read all direct messages after logging in to the Instagram account and give a pre-defined response if someone sent a message with the number 2. I will do this.  I did Selenium, but I ran into a problem and I could not read all the received messages, and I want to do it with Python, please help me.

Send auto reply messege in instagram using python